# Why following Jquery codes work in IE and chrome but not work in Safari?

Tags: jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>testsasfa</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js' type='text/javascript'>
        </script>
        <script src='http://media.lib.byu.edu/js/jquery/plugins/jquery.livequery-1.0.3.js' type='text/javascript'>
        </script>
        <style type='text/css'>

            .general {
                display: none;
            }

            .show {
                display: block;
            }

            .title {
                background-color: #0099CC;
                font-size: 30px;
                color: white;
            }

            .subtitle {
                font-style: italic;
            }

            textarea {
                height: 70px;
                width: 890px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            jQuery.noConflict();
            $(function(){
                $('#generalTitle').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('.general').toggleClass("show");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td id='generalTitle' class='title'>
                General Information
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="general">
                    <tr class='subtitle'>
                        <td>
                            Definition
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <textarea id="div1">
                            </textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1998 is calling, they want their HTML back.

Comment: 1.  What doesn't work?
2.  Owww, that code is painfully bad.  Why use tables to act as divs?!

Comment: @Raynos it's not that bad - I don't see any `<font>` tags and he's still using `class="xxx"`  :)

Answer (score 6):

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js' type='text/javascript'>
    </script>
```

Your including jQuery thrice. This is a mess.

You clearly don't know what your doing. Go buy a web development book. Or at least read the MDN

Comment: Unsure what it's supposed to do, but looking at the code, a click on the heading expands part of the table.  If that is what it is supposed to do, then it seems to be working here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/g8Hr3/ after removing the dup jQuery includes.

Comment: Thanks, that is what exactly I want to do. But in Safari, it is really not work. Is that because .click is not allowed in Safari, especially, Ipad?

Answer (score 0):

If you call `jQuery.noConflict()` then you shouldnt (supposed to be CANT) use the `$` selector unless you scope it:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
//scope it
(function($){
  // you can now use $ to access jQuery in here only.
})(jQuery);
```